# Print the text of GtkTextView

Tags: gtk, gtktextview

How can I print (for example in a label) the text into a GtkTextView?
For GtkLabel and GtkEntry there are gtk_label_get_text() and gtk_entry_get_text(), but for GtkTextView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

```
GtkTextIter start, end;
GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (text_view);
gchar *text;

gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (buffer, &start, &end);
text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (buffer, &start, &end, FALSE);
```

Don't forget to `g_free (text)` when no longer needed.

Comment: `gchar` is the same as `char`, so you can use `char*` just as well.

Answer (score 7):

Based on doublep's answer, for quick copy/paste:

```
char *get_text_of_textview(GtkWidget *text_view) {
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer((GtkTextView *)text_view);
    gchar *text;
    gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(buffer, &start, &end);
    text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(buffer, &start, &end, FALSE);
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for you people from Google, this is the way it's done in python:

```
def getText(textview):
    buffer = textview.get_buffer()
    startIter, endIter = buffer.get_bounds()    
    text = buffer.get_text(startIter, endIter, False) 
    return text
```